# Android All Background Services are not closing on exit?They are Restarting

Tags: android, onclick, exit

I followed [this](https://github.com/vanilla-fm/Online-Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/webradio/MainActivity.java) to get online web radio stream in android

So here I have added this to exit app at one click

```
    append = findViewById(R.id.a_exit);
    append.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ⓘ  Exit ! " +  getString(R.string.app_name));
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click Yes to Exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);

                /*if (isMyServiceRunning(BackgroundMusicService.class)) {
                    ctx.stopService(new Intent(ctx, BackgroundMusicService.class));
                }*/

                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //homeIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                /*if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
                    finish();
                }*/
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0);
            }
        })

         .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        }

    });
```

So here after this it ending the Radio and App and Starting app in background and Playing the previous radio station Stream......... Please Help me on this kind

I want to Exit the entire app on one click inculuding background Services

**Update**

All I am trying to do is Killing [this](https://github.com/vanilla-fm/Online-Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/webradio/service/BackgroundMusicService.java) activity which is running at background even After app exit

Afeter Adding this

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundMusicService.class));
```

Its stopping But Still in Notification its showing that Playing and Its connecting to server but not playing ..

Here I want to kill that activity along with app exit.. Because its using network at background...

Answer (score 1):

Use `stopService` and `finish` not `System.exit()`, also don't put `START_STICKY` inside `Service`. Use like:

```
 ...// inside dialog
  ...
 //System.exit(0);
 finish();
 stopService(new Intent(main_class.this, Service_to_stop.class));
```

Comment: Thanks @W4R10CK sir with your answer its stopping audio but background its connecting to network and notification is not  stopping its just restarting notification... but app main activity is closed

Comment: Don't put `START_STICKY` inside Service Class.

Comment: I have Given already .. Thanks After adding this its closing `NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nMgr.cancelAll();`    But back end its consuming internet... Please help

Comment: In place of `START_STICKY` use `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: there is my service link https://github.com/vanilla-fm/Online-Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/webradio/service/BackgroundMusicService.java